# Are spaces of finite sequences nuclear?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $I$ be some index set and $c_{00}$ the set of functions $c$ from $I$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $c(i) \neq 0$ for only finitely many $i \in I$.

Let this space carry the locally conves topology induced by the seminorms
$$ \|c\|_f := \sum_{i \in I} c(i) f(i)$$
where $f \in \mathbb{C}^I$ is any function.

Is this space nuclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean $\|c\|_f= \sum_i |c(i)f(i)|$. Then the space is nuclear if and only if $I$ is countable.

If $I=\mathbb N$ and $f$ is a weight function you put $g(i)=2^i f(i)$ to obtain rather easily the nuclearity of the canonical map $X_g \to X_f$, where $X_f$ is the (Hausdorff-) completion of $(c_{00},\|\cdot\|_f)$ which is the weighted space
$\ell_1(f)=\lbrace (x_i)_{i\in I}: \sum_i |x(i)f(i)|<\infty\rbrace$.

If $I$ is uncountable, put $f(i)=1$ and assume that there is $g\ge f$ such that
the map $J:X_g\to X_f$ is nuclear with a nuclear representation
$J=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \phi_n \otimes y_n$. Each $y_n \in \ell_1(f)$ has countable support $S_n$ so that $J(x)$ has support in the countable set $S=\bigcup_n S_n$ for every $x\in X_g$
(because $\lbrace y\in\ell_1(f):$ support$(y)\subseteq S\rbrace$ is closed).
For $x=\delta_i$ with $i\in I\setminus S$ you get a contradiction.